# ¿Cómo crear 2 ventanas modales de diferente tamaño, contenido y estilo?

Tags: modal, bootstrap-5

Estoy empleando la libreria de Bootstrap 5 y lo que quiero es crear 2 ventanas modales pero de diferente tamaño.
Por ejemplo, mi primera ventana modal tendra un height: 330px y mi segunda ventana modal un height:200px, y asimismo cambiando el color de background diferente para ambas.
¿Cómo puedo hacer ese cambio?
Agradezco mucho el apoyo de la comunidad.
Saludos

```
.modal-content form{
position: relative;
margin-top: 16px; 
min-height: 330px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-content1 form{
position: relative;
margin-top: 16px; 
min-height: 200px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un servicio de código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: 2 ventanas modales que se ejecuten al mismo tiempo?

Comment: No, sino que un boton llame una ventana modal de estilo 1 y otro boton llame a otra ventana modal de estilo 2, por separado, no al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dar el tamaño es fácil es crear una nueva clase (.class), darle el tamaño y el color o darle un identificador (#id) y darle los mismos atributos, a continuación el código de ejemplo que solo edite el ejemplo del sitio oficial de Bootstrap:

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/][1]

[1]: Ejemplo Modal

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ejemploModalUno">
                        Boton Uno
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ejemploModalDos">
                        Botón Dos
                    </button>
                    <style>
                        #model-content-uno
                        {
                            height: 330px;
                            background-color: lightcyan;
                        }

                        #model-content-dos
                        {
                            height: 200px;
                            background-color: lightyellow;
                        }
                    </style>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="ejemploModalUno" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content" id="model-content-uno">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Alerta Modal Uno</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Cuerpo del Modal uno by Sergio
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="ejemploModalDos" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content" id="model-content-dos">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Alerta Modal Dos</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Cuerpo del Modal dos by Sergio
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```